# replace url query string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically generated buttons with `url` using data attributes

```
<button class="btn-Add" type="button" data-add-url="/AddProductToCart?mobileNo=__param__&amp;
productId=2051&amp;quantity=1">Add to Cart</button>
```

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mobileNo = 0;
    $(".btn-Add").click(function () {
        mobileNo = $(this).parent('.pro-Group').find('input[type=text]').val();
        var postURL = $(this).data('add-url');
        postURL.replace('__param__', mobileNo);
        alert(postURL); // i can still see __param__ , its not replaced
    });
});
```

Why query string value is not replaced after using replace method ?

Comment: `postURL = postURL.replace('__param__', mobileNo);` ??

Comment: @Sysix , Thanks for the comment and finding my mistake, it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript Strings are immutable. So once their value got assigned  they can't changes their values.

So you have to reassign them with new changes or have to receive them in new variables. Generally we reassign as there is no need of new variable to be introduced unless you need old value .

```
  postURL = postURL.replace('__param__', mobileNo);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and finding my mistake, it works now. Initially I thought it would work without reassigning them.

Comment: @stom You are correct in case mutable objects. You are welcome.

Comment: @ANS  for the description +1