# query string value is null C#, Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I know this is an old question and answered multiple times, but they don't solve my problem. I've seen several questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402675/get-query-string-values-when-submitting-a-form-mvc3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657482/replace-url-query-string-value).

So I'm simply trying to pass my ID value using querystring like :-

```
$scope.MaterialView = function (ID) {
        ClassFactory.RedirectMaterialView(ID).then(function (d) {
            //$window.open(d.data, '_blank');
            var queryString = d.data + '?id=' + ID;
            var popup = window.open(queryString, '_blank');

            if (popup) {
                popup.onload = function () {
                    console.log(popup.innerHeight > 0 ? '' : alert('Pop_Up Blocked By Your Browser'));
                }
            } else {
                alert('Pop_Up Blocked By Your Browser');
            }
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Cannot Redirect to Material');
        })
    }
```

Now this is giving me result as :-

```
http://localhost:31015/Home/ClassMaterial?id=122
```

But I'm not able to access id in my c#.

I tried this:-

```
dbundle.MaterialFetchID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

and this:-

```
public ListViewModel FetchMaterialDetail(string id)    
    {
        dbundle = (DataBundle)TempData["DBundle"];
        dbundle.MaterialFetchID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
```

Both of them are giving me null values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `dbundle.MaterialFetchID....` where did you write this code? In controller action? Can you share the relevant code of `ClassMaterial` action method?

Comment: you mean it is calling the action method but the id value is not getting passed?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes you gave me the hint for error. It was going to the ClassMaterial action Method. With your help I resolved it. Thanks.